# using smtp gmail to sending mail

Tags: java

i would like to know how to send mail from java program. i have written java mailing program nothing wrong in that. but i got unknow SMTP port 465 even i used g mail server port 465.
i want to know is there any option need to enable in my computer.
please let  me know what are required, step by step 
i am using windows 7 and want to use gmail server..

your effort will  be very thankfully.

please let me know any error in following ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
    at mail1.SendMailSSL.main(SendMailSSL.java:44)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at mail1.SendMailSSL.main(SendMailSSL.java:39)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1611)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1035)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:124)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1139)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:503)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:234)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1672)
```

Comment: Are you doing this from your home machine? Some ISPs block access to external SMTP servers as an anti-spam measure.

Comment: Look further down in the stack trace.  The error has to do with SSL.  Did you write SSL-handling code?

Comment: yes i am doing form my personal? please tell me what i do

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for me perfectly. You need to import GMail smtp server certificate into your truststore

1. Get Gmail smtp server certificate with openssl command

   "s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465"
2. Save output between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" (including that prefix/suffix) into file "gmail.cert"
3. Import this certificate file into your keystore (for Linux it will need sudo)

   keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -file gmail.cert
4. Restart your java app to propagate changes

Credits to the: http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2012/04/import-gmail-certificate-into-java.html

OpenSSL can be downloaded here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

Comment: But what about embedded application that runs into different hosts ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` to see if you can connect.  This should give you an indication if you are connecting or not.  Also try port 587 (Submission/StartTLS) which should give a visible header.

Telnet is not installed by default on Windows 7.  You should be able to install it from the command line with the command `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"`.

Once you are connecting you will need to authenticate with a gmail id and password to send mail.  It would appear your code is not connecting yet.

Answer (score 0):

Look for addtional clues by adding the debug option to whatever props you are passing when getting the session.  I think you will see that you are actually connecting to gmail's backend since your exception is during send() and not during connect() which means the host/port/id/psw you are using are all likely correct (unless there is some sort of lazy connect happening).

```
props.put("mail.debug", "" + true); // Enable debug mode
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpId, psw);
    }
});
```

Your debug output should look something like:

```
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
9 220 mx.google.com ESMTP cpxgxgxgxgxgxgb.3
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an SSLSocket, like this?

```
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) 
                            SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).
                            createSocket(InetAddress.getByName("smtp.gmail.com"), 465);
```