# I am using jenkins email notification and unable to send mails when i set system date to past date (say 1 month back)

Tags: java, ssl, smtp, pki

I am able to send a mail when I set system date to current date but when I set system date to past date I get the following error:

```
Failed to send out e-mail
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
       PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
         timestamp check failed
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
```

Requirement: it has to work in past date only. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [using smtp gmail to sending mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644163/using-smtp-gmail-to-sending-mail) already?

Comment: yes configuration what i made is working fine i can able to send mail for current system date.

Comment: @GeroldBroser when i set system date to past date getting error as mentioned above

Comment: Please any one can help me out to solve this problem